# CSS after pseudo class text decoration in link

Tags: css, pseudo-class

The goal of my question is to create a code which adds the filetype after a link (so that people know whether they should expect any special files). Now there are options to do this using an image, but I don't really like it and I would prefer to have the file type between square brackets in a different size. My approach is to use the :after pseudoclass in the following way

```
a[href$='.doc']:after, a[href$='.rtf']:after {
content: " [DOC]";
font-family: Monospace;
font-size: 60%;
font-weight:bolder;
color:red;
position:relative;
top: -0.8em;    
}
```

However, this gets me a very strange problem. The content seems to be in a block which is part of the link. Therefore the link underlining continues after the link under the "[DOC]".

So the question is pretty straightforward: Is there a way to either do this in another way or to make sure that I can control what is under the "[DOC]" separately from what is under the link?

Comment: asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238881/text-decoration-and-the-after-pseudo-element-revisited see also doctype question: http://doctype.com/%E2%80%9Ctextdecoration%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%9Cafter%E2%80%9D-pseudoelement

Answer (score 4):

Try adding display: inline-block;

```
a[href$='.doc']:after, a[href$='.rtf']:after {
content: " [DOC]";
display: inline-block;
font-family: Monospace;
font-size: 60%;
font-weight:bolder;
color:red;
position:relative;
top: -0.8em;    
}
```

not tested in IE but I think IE has trouble with attribute selectors and :after or both.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/fsEUE/1/ - it works in Chrome, Opera; but unfortunately not in Firefox, IE8, Safari. +1 anyway.

Comment: I use it with a background image instead of the content and it seems to work better: http://jsfiddle.net/imaginekitty/fsEUE/2/

Comment: Yup, that works in "every" browser. This is a good idea if the OP is happy to use an image instead.

Answer (score 3):

I hope someone will swoop down and point out a cleaner way, but this works:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/fsEUE/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="lol.doc"><span>lol</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none
}
a span {
    text-decoration: underline
}
a[href$='.doc']:after, a[href$='.rtf']:after {
    content: " [DOC]";
    font-family: Monospace;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight:bolder;
    color:red;
    position:relative;
    top: -0.8em;
}
```

Comment: @roryf: I'm glad that nobody seems to have found a cleaner fix in your linked questions. Then again, I wish there was a cleaner fix :)

Answer (score 1):

All: I will probably stick to an image since that seems to be a bit more robust (in terms of supporting browsers). My naive view of the world, that a plain text should always be easier than an image is wrong in this case ;).

Comment: Even if you just make an image that says " [DOC]" at least you'll have foreknowledge of it's width so that you can add the correct padding and not have to worry about if the end user resizes their browser text.

Comment: Wait, are you the same person that asked the question?

Comment: @mark123: It's the same person on another account. You can tell this by the fact that they have the same Gravatar, which means they have the same email address.

Comment: Whoops! The advantage of registering is that you always appear by the same name. I still have to get into the details of replying in the right layer and so on... Anyhow: thanks voor the hint!