# Override “text-decoration: line-through” for “:before/:after” pseudo class

Tags: html, css

Do you know why the `line-through` text-decoration for `:before` isn’t being overridden?

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FZJYW/**

HTML

```
<p>Should be strike-through</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

p:before {
  content: "Should not be strike-through. ";
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Any ideas how to make only part of text `line-through` without adding an extra element, like `<span>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [“text-decoration” and the “:after” pseudo-element, revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238881/text-decoration-and-the-after-pseudo-element-revisited)

Answer (score 11):

Add `display: inline-block` to the pseudo element's css properties