# Remove text-decoration underline, for a:after in css

Tags: html, css, navigation, text-decorations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“text-decoration” and the “:after” pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180910/text-decoration-and-the-after-pseudo-element)
>   [“text-decoration” and the “:after” pseudo-element, revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238881/text-decoration-and-the-after-pseudo-element-revisited)

I am making a navigation links using `<a>` tags Following is the html

```
<div class="nav_container">
    <a class="panel" href="demolink">menu1</a>
    <a class="panel" href="demolink">menu2</a>
    <a class="panel" href="demolink">menu3</a>
</div>
```

And applying the `:after` css property to put a pipeline for the divider

```
.panel:after{
    content:"|";
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.panel:last-child:after{
    content:"";
}
```

I want to put underline when the menu is selected for that I am applying a class called selected

```
.panel.selected {
    text-decoratoion:underline;
}
```

But the problem is The pipline after menu "|" is also having the underline and I want to remove it. I even tried to change the css for `.panle:after` as follows,

```
.panel:after{
    content:"|";
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

But still the underline is there.

Any suggestion,
Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238881/text-decoration-and-the-after-pseudo-element-revisited

Comment: This can't be done, and it's also a duplicate.

Comment: Another way you could do it is replace the text-decoration with none and apply the underline on the text with a border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc, and for the :after use a border-bottom: 1px solid white; that way no underline will be applied to the :after element but an underline will be on the text. simple and should work fine. Use padding on the :after if you want to have an empty gap between the :after element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use one another method also for your question :- [demo](http://tinkerbin.com/49ZWfcb1)

I have tried with minimized code :-

```css
.nav_container a {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav_container a+a {
  color: red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 7px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_container">
  <a href="demolink">menu1</a>
  <a href="demolink">menu2</a>
  <a href="demolink">menu3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 31):

**Try this one:**

```css
.panel:after {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

**Or use the following:**

```css
.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.panel:after {
  content: '';
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  left: -10px;
  top: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.panel:first-child:after {
  display: none;
}

.panel:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_container">
  <a class="panel" href="demolink">menu1</a>
  <a class="panel" href="demolink">menu2</a>
  <a class="panel" href="demolink">menu3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: atleast read the question first

Comment: Why did this work for me? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what your `.panel.selected {}` part does. However you can make the link underlined when it is **focused** by using this.

> `.panel:focus {text-decoration:underline;}`

And you can remove the underline from **links** and **pipes(|)** like this.

> `.panel:link {text-decoration:none;}`

Add above two in to your page and check.

Answer (score -1):

A simple menu for your requirement.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="last-menu"><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
<li class="last-menu"><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
}

.menu ul{
    list-style:none;
}

.menu li{
    float:left;

}

.last-menu{
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```